# Return value of a promise to a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with outputting the values of a promise function.

```
$scope.getTeacher = function(teacherAbr) {
  var promise = dataService.getTeacher(teacherAbr);

  var testje = promise.then(function(payload) {
    return payload;
  });

  return testje; // outputs an d object, not the direct payload values
};
```

The output of this controller function is this:
[image: output of function]

However, when I'm doing `testje.$$state` it returns `undefined`. How can I output the `value` object? I can't output the `payload` variable in a new $scope, because this data is dynamic.

Here is a [simplified version of this on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/135lnOtJhq79GP9cvCH6?p=preview).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the way you think about things when you work with asynchronous code. You no longer *return* values, instead you use Promise or callback patterns to invoke code when data becomes available.

In your case your factory can be:

```
.factory('dataService', function($http, $log, $q) {
    return {
        getTeacher: function(teacher) {
            // Originally this was a jsonp request ('/teacher/' + teacher)
            return $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two').then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function() {
                $log.error(msg, code);
            })
        }
    };
});
```

And usage in controller:

```
dataService.getTeacher('Lanc').then(function(data) {
    $scope.teacher = data;
});
```

Also `$http.get` already returns promise, so you don't have to create one more with `$q.defer()`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FNYmZg9NJR7GpjgKkWd6?p=preview

#### UPD

Here is another effort for combining lessons with teachers.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/SXT5QaiZuiQGZe2Z6pb4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use this in a template with ng-repeat? There are multiple teachers in the ng-controller. So I need something like this: `<div ng-repeat="teacher in getTeacher(lesson.teacher)"></div>`

Comment: You simply use `$scope.teachers` object in template: `<div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers)"></div>`.

Comment: That's not the problem unfortunately, I've made a [better demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/135lnOtJhq79GP9cvCH6?p=preview) to illustrate it. Thank you very much for helping me btw :).

Comment: I see what your problem is.. Then it becomes more complicated. See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXT5QaiZuiQGZe2Z6pb4?p=preview).

Comment: You can't achieve it like your are trying to do it. So you need to combine teacher info with lesson outside of `ngRepeat`. I would recommend to make your webserver do it: it's very easy with LEFT JOINS, etc. Or you can do it like I did in another demo. See updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna go with the `$q.all()` method. Can't modify the webserver output unfortunately. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

//in your services file

```
  return {
      getTeacher: function (teacher) {
        // Originally this was a jsonp request ('/teacher/' + teacher)
       return $http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two')

        })
```

//change the controller to this

```
dataService.getTeacher(teacherAbr).then(function(msg){

     $scope.getdata=msg.data;
      console.log("From server"+msg.data);

});
```